# Verificar se uma data e hora (timestamp) representa o dia atual

Tags: mysql, sql

Eu tenho uma tabela com o seguinte campo: dh_envio (TIMESTAMP) e quero montar uma query para pegar todos os registros dessa tabela na qual a dh_envio seja igual a data atual (HOJE).

Eu pensei da seguinte forma:

```
WHERE dh.envio BEETWEEN '2014-02-17 00:00:00' AND '2014-02-17 23:59:59'
```

Existe alguma forma melhorar? como o uso de alguma constante do MySQL? Pois dessa forma eu preciso pegar a data programaticamente.

Comment: Vai que você pega uma data 23:59:59 e 50 centésimos. O ideal seria comparar >= 00:00 e < 00:00 do dia seguinte. Também é bom verificar como o banco lida com a questão do fuso horário.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A alternativa para fazer isso com SQL puro, sem preparar a data antes de executar a querie é

```
WHERE DATE(dh.envio) = DATE(NOW())
```

**Porém não faça isso**. Essa alternativa automática tem performance pior e só deve ser usada se estiver com preguiça e não quiser tomar proveito de cache de query e estiver disposto a fazer isso ao imaginar que essa query irá calcular a data de TODA sua tabela.

Por isso, a forma como está fazendo atualmente é performática. A não ser que tenha algo contra ela, permaneça desse modo.

Comment: Muito obrigado, era isso mesmo. A query vai rodar somente uma x no dia, com relação a performance é bem tranquilo.

Answer (score 0):

Eu sempre uso na linguagem pois não depende do processamento do BD, nesse seu caso você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE dh.envio = (DIA ATUAL NA PROGRAMAÇÃO);
```

Se for PHP por exemplo:

```
   $sql="SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE dh.envio =". NOW();
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score -1):

```
WHERE DATE(dh.envio) = DATE(NOW())
```

Comment: Olá Felipe, podes juntar uma explicação a essa condição sobre porque achas que ela resolve o problema? Assim a resposta fica mais completa.